Time clauses with present perfect

I will tell him that when I call him

I will tell him that when I have called him

I will eat a lot when I get to Spain

I will eat a lot when I have gotten to Spain


1 means that I will tell him something during the phone call. The same applies to 3. I will eat a lot during my time in Spain. What about 2? Does it mean after I rang but it is possible that we are still  connected or it is all finished and we hung up and then I met him somewhere and tell him the news? 4 is it possible that I am still in Spain or not and 4 means after my trip is finished and once I am back home I eat a lot

@Kate Bunting if you could answer, that would be awesome

I would understand (2) to mean 'after the phone call has finished', which is nonsense. As a Brit I don't use gotten. 'When I have got to Spain' is OK, but to me it carries a suggestion that the journey will be long or difficult - 'when I have [finally] arrived there...'

What is your problem with these sentences? Please use better spacing so your paragraph is more easily readable. It makes my eyes glaze over. We generally use contracted forms in speech.
